# How to make my app visible in account setting page android using ionic 2?

Tags: android, ionic2, hybrid-mobile-app

Hello folks am new for hybrid application development , My doubt is how to add my app in accounts page inside setting in mobile , I have done that in native which is account authenticator so that i can make my app visible in account page, similarly how can i make my app visible in that page while developing with ionic 2 
is that possible ? i have searched a lot but couldn't find any solution can somebody guide me how to make it possible ? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Have you found out any solution?